# Show/Hide Content with multiple checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, checkbox

I need to hide a SVG graphic and display an icon. 
The event must be handled by an invisible checkbox. The issue is that all checkboxes gets selected when the `onchange` event is fired, so all icons shows up and all inputs gets selected.

Any idea how to set the event handler individually for each `input[type="checkbox"]`?

```js
var $checkbox = $('.form-control'),
  $iconCheck = $('.check-circle'),
  $imgSVG = $('.img');

  $($checkbox).on('change', function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
      $iconCheck.removeClass('d-none');
      $imgSVG.addClass('d-none');
    } else {
      $iconCheck.addClass('d-none');
      $imgSVG.removeClass('d-none');
    }
  });
```

```css
img {
  display: block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
}
.d-none {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card">
  <figure>
    <img class="img" src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/halloween-29/64/ghost-512.png" alt="">
    <i class="check-circle d-none">CHECKED!</i>
  </figure>
  <label for="checkboxTerror">Terror</label>
  <input id="checkboxTerror" type="checkbox" class="form-control">
</div>


<div class="card">
  <figure>
    <img class="img" src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/icons8/ios7/256/Cinema-Comedy-2-icon.png" alt="">
    <i class="check-circle d-none">CHECKED!</i>
  </figure>
  <label for="checkboxTerror">Comedy</label>
  <input id="checkboxTerror" type="checkbox" class="form-control">
</div>
```

**Screenshot Example**

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By defining the three variables `$checkbox`, `$iconCheck` and `$imgSVG` outside of the `$($checkbox).on('change', ...)`, you are selecting every existing element, not the elements related to the checkbox.

You should instead use `$('.form-control').each(...)` and apply a `change` event to each one individually. Then you can find the nearest image with `$(this).parent().find('...')`.

**Here is a working example:**

```js
$('.form-control').each(function() {
  $(this).on('change', function() {
    let $iconCheck = $(this).parent().find('.check-circle');
    let $imgSVG = $(this).parent().find('.img');

    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
      $iconCheck.removeClass('d-none');
      $imgSVG.addClass('d-none');
    } else {
      $iconCheck.addClass('d-none');
      $imgSVG.removeClass('d-none');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
img {
  display: block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
}

.d-none {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card">
  <figure>
    <img class="img" src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/halloween-29/64/ghost-512.png" alt="">
    <i class="check-circle d-none">CHECKED!</i>
  </figure>
  <label for="checkboxTerror">Terror</label>
  <input id="checkboxTerror" type="checkbox" class="form-control">
</div>


<div class="card">
  <figure>
    <img class="img" src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/icons8/ios7/256/Cinema-Comedy-2-icon.png" alt="">
    <i class="check-circle d-none">CHECKED!</i>
  </figure>
  <label for="checkboxTerror">Comedy</label>
  <input id="checkboxTerror" type="checkbox" class="form-control">
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

I have an answer without `javascript`

You can solve with `CSS Trick` like that.

```js
/*var $checkbox = $('.form-control'),
  $iconCheck = $('.check-circle'),
  $imgSVG = $('.img');

  $($checkbox).on('change', function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
      $(this).parent().children('.check-circle').removeClass('d-none');
      //$iconCheck.removeClass('d-none');
      $imgSVG.addClass('d-none');
    } else {
      $iconCheck.addClass('d-none');
      $imgSVG.removeClass('d-none');
    }
  });*/
```

```css
img {
  display: block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
}
.d-none {
  display: none;
}
input[type=checkbox].form-control:checked + figure > img{
  display: none;
}
input[type=checkbox].form-control:checked + figure > .check-circle{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card">
  <label for="checkboxTerror">Terror</label>
  <input id="checkboxTerror1" type="checkbox" class="form-control">
  <figure>
    <img class="img" src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/halloween-29/64/ghost-512.png" alt="">
    <i class="check-circle d-none">CHECKED!</i>
  </figure>
  
</div>


<div class="card">
  <label for="checkboxTerror">Comedy</label>
  <input id="checkboxTerror2" type="checkbox" class="form-control">
  <figure>
    <img class="img" src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/icons8/ios7/256/Cinema-Comedy-2-icon.png" alt="">
    <i class="check-circle d-none">CHECKED!</i>
  </figure>
   
</div>
```